# Visual studio method sequence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Is there any built-in option in visual studio 2013, or an add-on that could record which methods of ASP.NET application are called at some time and in which sequence?

Example:

```
request();
processRequest();
sendResponse();
```

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool (developed by me, 30-day trial) to monitor which methods of an ASP.NET application are called.

Comment: nice product :) a bit expensive for my pockets, but very interesting

Comment: http://dotnetmonitor.vlasovstudio.com/2012/01/19/monitoring-a-net-application-running-in-iis/ tried this, and it doesnt work.. It starts but there is nothing in my runtime flow window... using vs 2013 proffesional

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in method to record method executions, what you can do, using Diagnostic and Reflection api, is something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyMethodName();
}

private static void WhatsMyName()
{
    StackFrame stackFrame = new StackFrame();
    MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
    Console.WriteLine(methodBase.Name );
    CalleedMethodName();
}

private static void CalleedMethodName()
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    StackFrame stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(1);
    MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
    Console.WriteLine( " Parent Method Name {0} ", methodBase.Name ); 
}
```

If you can use [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) you can write a Log Aspect like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogAspect: OnMethodBoundaryAspect {

public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", args.Method.Name, DateTime.Now);
}

public override void OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} complete: {1}",
    args.Method.Name, DateTime.Now);
}
```

}

and decorate every methods you would log,

```
public class MyClass {
[LogAspect]
public MyClass() { }
[LogAspect]
public void Method1() { }
[LogAspect]
public void Method2() { Method3(); }
[LogAspect]
private void Method3() { }
}
```

or else decorate enterely class:

```
[LogAspect]
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() { }

    public void Method1() { }

    public void Method2() { Method3(); }

    private void Method3() { }
    }
```

**EDIT**

[**You can also apply PostSharp aspect at namespace level**](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/multicasting)

> Applying an aspect to all types in a namespace.
>
> Even though we don't have to apply an aspect to all methods in all
>   classes in our application, adding the aspect attribute to every class
>   could still be an overwhelming task. If we want to apply our aspect in
>   a broad stroke we can make use of PostSharp's MulticastAttribute.
>
> The MulticastAttribute is a special attribute that will apply other
>   attributes throughout your codebase. Here's how we would use it.
>
> Open the AssemblyInfo.cs, or create a new file GlobalAspects.cs if you
>   prefer to keep things separate (the name of this file does not
>   matter). Add an [assembly:] attribute that references the aspect you
>   want applied. Add the AttributeTargetTypes property to the aspects's
>   constructor and define the namespace that you would like the aspect
>   applied to. [assembly: OurLoggingAspect(AttributeTargetTypes= 
>                               "OurCompany.OurApplication.Controllers.*")]

Comment: Is there maybe some 3rd party tool? I found MSE but it is only for exe apps... And I have too many methods in project to add LogAspect to every method...

Comment: RestSharp weaving can be applied also at assembly level, and a namespace level, in multicast

Comment: This is a great answer, but I cant use console.write or as in postsharp tracelistener in Main(), because I dont have Main in asp.net app

Comment: obviously I assume you would use NLOG or other Loggin frameworks, my example is only a generic example

Answer (score 1):

1. Put a debug point of the method you wanna debug
2. Go to `DEBUG > Windows > Call Stack`
3. This will list all the methods that were called before this method.

This option is available in almost all Visual Studio

Comment: seems the OP would record, not simply show, the execution of the methods

Comment: @Infer-On: You are right. If user wants to `record` then my solution makes no sense