# Getting overview of asp.net c# api calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-debugging, chrome-debugging

im currently debugging a larger asp.net mvc solution.
Now I'm pretty sure that a API call that is made serverside in c# is returning some kind of faulty value. The problem is though, the project has a LOT of api calls that looks like each other.

When i debug websites in the browser, I've gotten used to using the browsers developer tools "network" tab to view all external calls to API's done by javascript, and methods in the solution.

Is there some way to get a overview of all api calls that happens in c#/serverside, as they happen?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954169/visual-studio-method-sequence

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be looking at request logging? Even in Chrome, request capture is *not* part of debugging. You didn't specify which MVC version you use, or whether it's ASP.NET Old or ASP.NET Core, but all of them have some way of logging requests

Comment: Worst case, you can enable logging for `System.Net` classes and get all requests at a verbose level. You can also enable request logging in IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Getting overview of asp.net c# api calls

VS IDE does not have such option to view all the apis that are called during debugging.

But some VS extensions may realize it. You can try [Fiddler extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregTrevellick.OpenFiddler), [PostSharp extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PostSharpTechnologies.PostSharp) or use [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/)(thanks to **Sergey** for sharing it).

**In addition**, you can try to use encoding method like enable System.NET logging and get its request. See [this net framework network trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing) and [net core trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing).

If these do not meet your requirements, you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).(click **Suggest a Feature**).

**After that**, you could share the link with us here and anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention.

Comment: This should be a comment. Besides, one *can* enable System.NET logging and get all requests and more

Comment: Thanks for sharing the useful info.